# How to nest a namespaced ruby on rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller in a name spaced controller/user directory, so its first line is

```
class User::BookingsController < ApplicationController
```

I have set the routes as follows

```
  resources :users do
    namespace :user do
      resources :bookings
    end
  end
```

The path to index action is
`user_user_bookings_path` or

```
/users/:user_id/user/bookings(.:format)
```

which works fine, but the double `user_user` sounds like a Catch 22 joke. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What would you like to achieve? You *are* namespacing under "user" after all. You can try options like `as: nil`, but I think this will be even funnier (`user__bookings_path`).

What you can do is write every route by hand, something like:

```
resources :users do
  post 'bookings', to: 'user/bookings#create'
end
# => user_bookings_path, POST /users/:user_id/bookings
```

or if you want to preserve the URL

```
resources :users do
  post '/user/bookings', to: 'user/bookings#create', as: 'bookings'
end
# => user_bookings_path, POST /users/:user_id/user/bookings
```

Comment: Rather than add non-restful actions to a controller I now have a habit of creating a new controller for the new actions and namespacing it under the parent controller. I normally do this by just setting namespace for the parent controller and nesting the routes under that. But in this instance, I want to find the objects of the child controller using the user_id, which is why I have done this as shown.  It sounds to me that I am doing it the right way, and will just have to live with the echoing names?

Comment: Yup, that's what I think. In your case it happens that it's "users" and "user" that trip things up. I guess if it was `user_store_bookings_path` it would look nicer. But in this case, I'd say don't fight the framework. There are many other areas where it would be more beneficial to fight against Rails, but that's a different discussion :D.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
resources :users do
  resources :bookings
end
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing/) you can namespace your resource
by using the namespace block

```
namespace :api do
  resources :users
end
```

this would give you those routes:

- /api/users [GET, POST]
- /api/users/:id [GET, PUT, DELETE]

However you want to nest the resource within another resource ([docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)) you would do this:

```
resources :users do
  resources :bookings
end
```

Which would result in these routes:

- /users/:user_id/bookings [GET, POST]
- /users/:user_id/bookings/:id [GET, PUT, DELETE]

Because you have your controller scoped under `User` you have to set the user scope like this:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :bookings, module: :user
  end
```

Which results in those routes:

```
➜  playground rake routes
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
    user_bookings GET    /users/:user_id/bookings(.:format)          user/bookings#index
                  POST   /users/:user_id/bookings(.:format)          user/bookings#create
 new_user_booking GET    /users/:user_id/bookings/new(.:format)      user/bookings#new
edit_user_booking GET    /users/:user_id/bookings/:id/edit(.:format) user/bookings#edit
     user_booking GET    /users/:user_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      user/bookings#show
                  PATCH  /users/:user_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      user/bookings#update
                  PUT    /users/:user_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      user/bookings#update
                  DELETE /users/:user_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      user/bookings#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)                            users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                            users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                        users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                   users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#show
                  PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                        users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                        users#destroy
```